# Slow wifi upload with React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am facing a strange issue. I am building a React Native app that upload images to a simple PHP server using a REST API.

When the mobile app uploads the image to the server, the upload is very slow and even fails 50% of the time, but it sometimes work. But this only happens if I am on my home WIFI. If I disconnect and use 3G, the the upload is working very well.

Finally, if I upload the image from my computer, using the exact same WIFI connection, and a basic HTML form to perform the REST API POST request, then it is working very well! So the upload is only slow when using the wifi on the phone.

I tried to use the fetch API and XMLHttpRequest, both are acting the same way. I finally used XMLHttpRequest to get progress value.

Any idea about where it could comes from? Here is the upload code I use:

```
const image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();
const { uri, width, height, base64 } = image;
const splitUri = uri.split('.');
const ext = splitUri[splitUri.length - 1];
const name = `${splitUri[splitUri.length - 2]}.${ext}`;
const jwtToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');

const data = new FormData();
data.append('image', {
  uri: uri,
  type: `image/${ext}`,
  name,
});
data.append('authorization', jwtToken);
data.append('section', section);
data.append('width', width);
data.append('height', height);

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://my-website.com/api/add-image.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');

request.upload.onprogress = e => {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total * 100;
    this.setState({ modalProgress: percentComplete });
  }
};

request.onreadystatechange = e => {
  if (request.readyState !== 4) {
    return;
  }

  if (request.status === 200) {
    console.log('It worked');
      return;
    } else {
    console.log('It failed');
  }
  this.setState({ modalVisible: false });
};

request.send(data);
```

Comment: When does it happen? Dev or release mode?

Comment: Both. I am using Expo.io and it happens in local development mode or in a published production app.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work faster? I am stuck with the same exact issue, rest requests are super slow, only get requests are sometimes faster. I am using the same internet connection and checking with postman, in postman requests take 200ms, in RN it takes 4-10 seconds, tried using axios instead of fetch, still same results.

Comment: @Royi Mindel- did you solve that problem?

Comment: Which device you’re using? An emulator or the physical device

Comment: If you’re using the physical device, it surely have the fluctuation in upload speed. So you must compress the image before the upload process